# Through karate , how can I assert for not existence of node?

Tags: karate

In below json payload , How can I assert like D node is not present in response through karate .

```
{
DTO:{
content : [
A: "";
B: "";
C:""
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fuzzy-matching

```
* def response = { foo: 'bar' }
* match response == { foo: '#present', baz: '#notpresent' }
```

Your example is not well-formed JSON, please don't do that again.